# Can not format data in PWSTR variable to use in CopyFileW command

Tags: c++, unicode

I am very new to this, sorry about the horrible code below. I am trying to get the default path for FOLDERID_Profile and then add "\test.exe" to the end of it. Then i need to use this as the path to copy a file to. I was able to use the pSHGetKnownFolderPath method to store the profiles directory in PWSTR user_dir . Problem is, this is not an acceptable string format for the copy function.

So i used the following code to very crudely attempt to convert it to something the copy function could use.

```
            strcat((char *)user_dir,"\\test.exe");
            test7 = (LPCWSTR)user_dir;
            MessageBox(NULL,test7,L"WR test file",MB_OK);
```

i'm using a message box to check the path before using CopyFile(currentpath,test7,false); But this is giving me 㩃瑜獥⹴硥 . I am currently using

```
            CopyFileW(currentpath,L"C:\\Users\\Jenia\\test.exe",false);
```

as a workaround, but I really need this to work on other computers too...

I know I am messing up my ANSI vs Unicode formatting again, please tell me how to best achieve this goal. Let me know if you would like me to post the entire code block, but until i run that strcat method user_dir has the correct path just no file name for copy method.

more complete code below:

```
        #include <windows.h>
        #include <shlwapi.h>
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <Shlobj.h>

        LPCWSTR test7 = 0;
        PWSTR user_dir = 0;

        HMODULE hndl_shell32;
        lpSHGetKnownFolderPath pSHGetKnownFolderPath;

        hndl_shell32 = LoadLibrary(L"shell32");
        if (NULL != hndl_shell32)
        {
            pSHGetKnownFolderPath = (lpSHGetKnownFolderPath)
                GetProcAddress(hndl_shell32, "SHGetKnownFolderPath");

            if(pSHGetKnownFolderPath != NULL)
            {

                if (SUCCEEDED(pSHGetKnownFolderPath(
                                FOLDERID_Profile,
                                0,
                                NULL,
                                &user_dir)))
                {
 //I think this is the problem here
                        strcat((char *)user_dir,"\\test.exe");
                        test7 = (LPCWSTR)user_dir;
                        MessageBox(NULL,test7,L"WR test file",MB_OK);   
                }
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to locate function: %d\n",
                    GetLastError());
            }

        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load shell32.dll: %d\n", GetLastError());
        }
```

Comment: test 7 is declared as LPCWSTR test7 = 0; earlier in Main

Comment: Yes, you are messing ANSI and Unicode. Post minimal code sample which allows to understand what happens, including variable declarations. Or better read this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/446/Unicode-MBCS-and-Generic-text-mappings and fix your code.

Comment: I will be reading that, but it is late. I will post my code below and check comments in the morning! thanks.

Comment: edited OP with more complete code

Comment: Code sample which allows to understand what happens, `including variable declarations`

Comment: my bad, i think that covers all of em now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many errors here. You cannot `strcat` on pointer filled by `SHGetKnownFolderPath`. Assuming that all variables are Unicode, this should work with project with any character set:

```
LPWSTR test7 = 0;
WCHAR user_dir[MAX_PATH];
...
SHGetKnownFolderPath(... &test7);
...
wcscpy(user_dir, test7);
wcscat(user_dir, L"\\test.exe");
MessageBoxW(NULL,test7,L"WR test file",MB_OK);
```

Don't forget to release the pointer `test7` filled by `SHGetKnownFolderPath`.

Comment: this works too, im combining both of your solutions to shorten my code, wish i could give you both the answer :P . had to use wcscpy_s and wcscat_s though

Answer (score 0):

This shows the basic way to complete your task; you'll need to adapt it for your needs.

```
#include <ShlObj.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

void ShowTestPath()
{
    PWCHAR user_dir = NULL;
    WCHAR test_file_path[MAX_PATH];

    if (FAILED(SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Profile, 0, NULL, &user_dir)))
        return;

    if (FAILED(StringCchCopyW(test_file_path, MAX_PATH, user_dir)))
    {
        CoTaskMemFree(user_dir);
        return;
    }

    CoTaskMemFree(user_dir);

    if (FAILED(StringCchCatW(test_file_path, MAX_PATH, L"\\test.exe")))
        return;

    MessageBoxW(NULL, test_file_path, L"WR test file", MB_OK);
}
```

Comment: Thank you much, code is working now! StringCchCopyW and StringCchCatW is what i was looking for, did not know they existed! I will definitely be reading up on the article linked by Alex Farber , but im like a blind man stumbling about a room right now.